# How to filter the children for it's parents from a tables in PHP

Tags: php, performance, laravel-5, logic

I've created a products categories tables which contain data [here](https://jsonblob.com/582f3f32e4b0a828bd273041) in this table have both parent and it children by the ways I'm doing is work as well but it simply messy and not much better with many function that I have to call for each categories levels so I want to get some help to find out the better and easy way to filter all it children and get the same as below images result.
I think function that I have create really the same so it should have some better way revise and make it better than this one.

Here is my Helper function

```
<?php
namespace app\Helpers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController;

final class Helper extends AdminController
{

    public function setData($data)
    {
        return $this->data = $data;
    }

    final public function GetCats($selection = null, $name = null)
    {

        $html = '<select name="'.$name.'" class="'.$selection.'" >';
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $cats) {

            if ((int)$cats->parent_id === 0) {
                foreach ($cats->CategoryDescriptions as $d) {
                    $html .= '<option>';
                    $html .=  $d->name.$this->getChild1($cats->id, $d->name);
                    $html .= '</option>';
                }
            }
        }

        $html .= '</select>';
        echo $html;
    }

    private function getChild1($category_id, $parentName) //-->
    {
        $childs = '';
        foreach ($this->data as $child) {
            if ((int)$child->parent_id == (int)$category_id) {

                foreach ($child->CategoryDescriptions as $d) {

                    $childs .= '<option>' .$this->myspace(). $parentName . ' -> ';
                    $childs .= $d->name.$this->getChild2($child->id,$parentName, $d->name);
                    $childs .= '</option> ';
                }
            }
        }
        return $childs;
    }

    private function getChild2($category_id,$parentName,$name1) //-->
    {
        $childs = '';
        foreach ($this->data as $child) {
            if ((int)$child->parent_id == (int)$category_id) {

                foreach ($child->CategoryDescriptions as $d) {
                    $childs .= '<option>'.$this->myspace().$parentName.' --> '.$name1.' --> ';
                    $childs .= $d->name.$this->getChild3($child->id, $parentName, $name1,$d->name);

                    $childs .= '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        return $childs;
    }

    private function getChild3($category_id, $parentName, $name1,$name2) //-->
    {
        $childs = '';
        foreach ($this->data as $child) {
            if ((int)$child->parent_id == (int)$category_id) {

                foreach ($child->CategoryDescriptions as $d) {
                    $childs .= '<option>'.$this->myspace().$parentName.' --> '.$name1.' --> '.$name2.' --> ';
                    $childs .= $d->name.$this->getChildn4($child->id, $parentName, $name1,$name2,$d->name);
                    $childs .= '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        return $childs;
    }
    private function getChildn4($category_id, $parentName, $name1, $name2,$name3) //-->
    {
        $childs = '';
        foreach ($this->data as $child) {
            if ((int)$child->parent_id == (int)$category_id) {

                foreach ($child->CategoryDescriptions as $d) {
                    $childs .= '<option>'.$this->myspace().$parentName.' --> '.$name1.' --> '.$name2.' --> '.$name3.' --> ';
                    $childs .= $d->name.$this->getChildn5($child->id, $parentName, $name1,$name2,$name3,$d->name);
                    $childs .= '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        return $childs;
    }

    private function getChildn5($category_id, $parentName, $name1, $name2, $name3,$name4) //-->
        {
            $childs = '';
            foreach ($this->data as $child) {
                if ((int)$child->parent_id == (int)$category_id) {

                    foreach ($child->CategoryDescriptions as $d) {
                        $childs .= '<option>'.$this->myspace().$parentName.' --> '.$name1.' --> '.$name2.' --> '.$name3.' --> '.$name4.' --> ';
                        $childs .= $d->name.$this->getChildn5($child->id, $parentName, $name1,$name2,$name3,$d->name);
                        $childs .= '</option>';
                    }
                }
            }
            return $childs;
        }



    private function myspace (){
        return ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; ';
    }
}
```

Call this is class and method in View

```
<?PHP
  $helper = new Helper();
  $helper->setData($cat);
  $helper->GetCats('col-lg-9','cats');
  ?>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How can  I got some help from Someone?